# jquery hide and show in list

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="card-media">
  <!-- media container -->
  <div class="card-media-object-container">
    <div class="card-media-object"><img data-original="{{asset($ad->images()->first()->image_path.'/'.$ad->images()->first()->image_name)}}" height="125px" width="100%"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- body container -->
  <div class="card-media-body">
    <div class="card-media-body-top">
      <span class="subtle">{{$ad->time_elapsed_string($ad->created_at)}}</span>
    </div>
    <span class="title card-media-body-heading"><a href="ad/{{$ad->id}}">{{$ad->title}}</a></span>
    <div class="card-media-body-supporting-bottom">
      <span class="card-media-body-supporting-bottom-text subtle">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
          <li class="categorie">{{$ad->categorie->name}}</li>
          <li class="subcategorie">{{$ad->subcategorie->name}}</li>
          <li class="type active">{{$ad->type->name}}</li>
        </ol>
      </span>
      <span id="price" style="color: red;" class="card-media-body-supporting-bottom-text subtle u-float-right">{{$ad->price}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="card-media-body-supporting-bottom card-media-body-supporting-bottom-reveal">
      <span class="card-media-body-supporting-bottom-text subtle">{{$ad->phone}}</span>
      <a href="/ad/{{$ad->id}}" class="card-media-body-supporting-bottom-text card-media-link u-float-right">ДЭЛГЭРЭНГҮЙ</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my repeated list and i wanna hide by select value

```
  <select id="test" multiple class="form-control">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>100</option>
    <option>1000</option>
    <option>10000</option>
    <option>100000</option>
    <option>1000000</option>
  </select>
$('#test').on('change',function(){
  var selected = this.value;
  prices = $('#price');
  $.each(prices,function(){
  if(selected<$(this).text()){
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().hide();
  }
  if(selected>$(this).text()){
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().show();
  }
});
});
```

This is my jquery when i select value from select then if #price value < than select hide other list elements in my case card-media is list item.

Comment: What is `prices = $('#price');   $.each(prices, ...` supposed to do? If you select by `id` then `prices` will only contain a single element so using `$.each()` makes no sense. If all of the HTML shown repeats then it is invalid because `id` needs to be unique - use a class instead. Also, your two `if` tests use `<` and `>`, but don't allow for `==`.

Comment: I agree with @nnnnnn . you should use `class` in instead of `id` for `price`

Comment: You could also shorthen this up `$(this).parent().parent().parent().show()` to `$(this).closest('.card-media').show()` same thing for `.hide()`, if each list of medias are designed that its container class is `card-media`